# Adding custom order item meta programmatically in order creation

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce, hook

I tried a lot of different codes, but nothing help. Im calling a custom hook with custom function from custom event to create an order with existing product but with custom product meta in order item line.

```
function create_order($product_id, $customer_phone, $customer_email, $customer_name, $extra_service_id, $extra_service_name) {

$args = array(
        'Service ID' => $extra_service_id,
        'Service Name' => $extra_service_name
    );
    $quantity = 1;
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    $order = wc_create_order();
    $order->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);
    $address = array(
      'first_name' => $customer_name,
      'email'      => $customer_email,
      'phone'      => $customer_phone
    );
    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_status( 'wc-on-hold', 'Made in back-end' );
    $order->calculate_totals();
    $order->save();

}
add_action('create_order_hook', 'create_order', 10, 6);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using `woocommerce_add_order_item_meta` or `add_meta_data`. I added both ways.

```
add_action('create_order_hook', 'create_order', 10, 6);
function create_order($product_id, $customer_phone, $customer_email, $customer_name, $extra_service_id, $extra_service_name) {

    $args = array(
        'Service ID'   => $extra_service_id,
        'Service Name' => $extra_service_name
    );

    $quantity = 1;
    $product  = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $order    = wc_create_order();
    
    $order->add_product( $product, $quantity, $args);

    woocommerce_add_order_item_meta( $product_id, 'custom_key', 'custom value' );

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'custom_key', 'custom value', true );
    }
    
    $address = array(
      'first_name' => $customer_name,
      'email'      => $customer_email,
      'phone'      => $customer_phone
    );

    $order->set_address( $address, 'billing' );
    $order->set_status( 'wc-on-hold', 'Made in back-end' );
    $order->calculate_totals();

    $order->save();

}
```

Comment: Using the foreach, woocommerce_add_order_item_meta doesn't work for me. Thanks a lot for your answer @bhautik!